# Passing NSFetchedResultsController between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have 3 different view controllers that present same data. Basically they are presented one after another. They are presenting same entity that is fetched with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I am now pondering since these are same `NSFetchedResultsControllers`, should I just optimize things and create one, that I pass between controllers? Is there any downside to this, or even better is this good practice?

Also just passing dataset wouldn't suffice since i want controllers to react to changes to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I just optimize things and create one, that I pass between controllers?

Yes, minimising the overhead of performing a similar `fetchRequest` on init of every VC is a good practice.
A better alternate instead of passing the `NSFetchedResultsControllers` object between VCs would be -

- To completely abstract out all `FetchedResultsControllers` initialisation & delegate function implementations to a helper class christened like:
  `@interface CoreDataHelper: NSObject < NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate >`
- You'll need re-wiring of the `delegate` listeners & choose appropriate time for `allocating` & if required(not essential) `deallocating` of the `CoreDataHelper` instance
- A singleton `CoreDataHelper` will serve you well enough to handle all Core Data interactions.

Segregating `Model` interactions away & independent from `View` components enables for creating loosely-coupled modules, making them reusable & succinct.